# How to Replicate the Hover effect Shadow on Twitter Navigation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter

I am currently building Twitter from scratch using React and I've been trying to replicate the Hover effect on the Navigation (the round colour that appears when you hover over anything on the Nav side of the site). Please help me.

TwitterImageScreenshot:

[image: TwitterImageScreenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply CSS to change the background colour on Hover. 
You can use CSS :hover Selector. 
Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp